Can the opposite of divergent be embedded, good (synonym, antonym) synonymous set for this (synonym, antonym) pair
I was thinking, suppose your are reading text.
An image could be divergent (it leads you to go and do something else, putting down the text).
Or it could be embedding (it leads you to continue to view the text, without, putting, much, down the phone...
And, rarely, continue to do something and then pick the phone back up.
I wonder, what a good set of synonyms and antonyms would be for this synonym antonym pair.
Thanks.

Depending on exact context, focused and rambling might be a good starting point. But what works for, say, an image (literal artwork or a metaphorical "mental image") might not be so good if you're talking about someone's contribution to an ongoing conversation.

You are misusing both of those, for your information. An image is not said to be divergent. Divergent means this: Our readings or interpretations of the text diverge. Our readings are divergent. Or a cop could say: This image diverges from the other one which is supposedly of the same building.

Something that makes you want to continue reading is "engaging" or "interesting". An opposite would be "boring".
The simple opposite of "divergent" is "convergent". It's a reach (it's not apt) to apply that to how interesting a text is.
Try a browser search for a word followed by "synonym" or "antonym". There will be many results. One good source is (for example)
Merriam-Webster thesaurus engaging
